# JQuery silde divs back and fort horizontally

Tags: jquery, slide

I would like to slide w-1, w-2, w-3 div back and fort with right and left arrow. I know maybe I could use negative margin here but I'm not familiar with JQ so. I'm not sure that I should start with div's that are set up this way (floated left).

html:

```
    <html>

    <head>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="container">
            <div id="arrows">
                <ul class="button-group">
                     <li><a href="#" class="button">Left</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" class="button">Right</a></li>
                </ul>       
            </div> 
            <div id="windows">
                <div id="w-1" class="w">

                </div>
                <div id="w-2" class="w">

                </div> 
                <div id="w-3" class="w">

                </div> 
            </div>      
       </div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

css:

```
  body {
            padding: 20px;
    }
    #container {
            width: 800px;
            height: 500px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            background-color: #EAEAEA;
    }
    #arrows {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #888888;
    }
    #arrows a {
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
    }
    #windows {
            width: 100%;
            height: 80%;
            background-color: #EAEAEA;
            padding: 50px 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
    }
    .w {
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    #w-1 {
            background-color: red;
    }
    #w-2 {
            background-color: blue;
    }
    #w-3 {
            background-color: green;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: First you  need to add the `jquery` lib, lol ;)

Comment: I would if I knew what to add, linking jquery in header would not do me much good since I dont know how to set up functions.

Answer (score 0):

try this ::

```
   function onClickRight()
    {
        $('#mydiv').css({ 'right': '','animation-delay':'3s' }).animate({'right': '-95%'});
    }

    function RightToCenter()
    {
        $('#mydiv').css({ 'right': '','animation-delay':'3s' }).animate({'right': ''});
    }

    function onCLickLeft()
    { 
       $('#mydiv').css({ 'left': '','animation-delay':'3s' }).animate({'left': '-95%'});
    }

    function LefttoCenter()
    {
        $('#mydiv').css({ 'left': '','animation-delay':'3s' }).animate({'left': ''});
    }
```